# r adding double quotes in a character string of different length

Tags: r

I have a character string like this ;

emergency room OR emergency medicine OR cardiology

I would like to add double quotes in all terms except 'OR'. So the final result should be

"emergency room" OR "emergency medicine" OR "cardiology"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
cat(paste0('"',paste0(unlist(strsplit(string," OR ")),collapse='" OR "'),'"'))
"emergency room" OR "emergency medicine" OR "cardiology"
```

In your string you will have backslash before special character `"`

```
paste0('"',paste0(unlist(strsplit(string," OR ")),collapse='" OR "'),'"')
[1] "\"emergency room\" OR \"emergency medicine\" OR \"cardiology\""
```

Answer (score 1):

You can escape the quotation marks using a backslash.

Check out 
[How to display text with Quotes in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15204442/how-to-display-text-with-quotes-in-r)

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit of a hack, but it works just fine:

```
s <- 'emergency room OR emergency medicine OR cardiology'

sq <- sprintf('"%s"',paste0(str_split(s,' OR ')[[1]],collapse = '" OR "')))

cat(sq)
#"emergency room" OR "emergency medicine" OR "cardiology"

or even simpler:

sq <- sprintf('"%s"',gsub(' OR ','" OR "',s))

cat(sq)

#"emergency room" OR "emergency medicine" OR "cardiology"
```

Comment: I tried using the following code

sq <- sprintf('"%s"',gsub(' OR ','" OR "',s))

cat(sq)

But, I am not able to assign the result of above expression to a new object. So in continuation of your code when i use

finalkeywords <- cat(sq)

> finalkeywords
NULL

I do not understand why this is happening?

Comment: `cat` is only outputs the string to the console, so running `finalkeywords <- cat(sq)` will result in `NULL` - the important part is `sprintf('"%s"',gsub(' OR ','" OR "',s))`, with `s` being your string which needs double quotes

Comment: You can't assign the output of `cat` to a variable. Double quotes in a string in `R` need to be escaped with a backslash, hence `\"` is the correct representation - you can see that if you just run `sq` or `print(sq)`

Comment: I am sorry. I understood your point that cat only outputs the string to the console. But my point is how can I assign the resulting string with double quotes to a new object?

Comment: in `R`, `\"Hello World\"` would be the accurate character string of "Hello World"

Comment: Undestood @Val. Thank you so much for putting so much efforts.

Comment: Glad I could help!